# How to setup default attributes in a ruby model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models

I have a model `User` and when I create one, I want to pragmatically setup some API keys and what not, specifically:
`@user.apikey = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(BCrypt::Password.create("jibberish").to_s)`

I want to be able to run `User.create!(:email=>"something@test.com")` and have it create a user with a randomly generated API key, and secret.

I currently am doing this in the controller, but when I tried to add a default user to the `seeds.rb` file, I am getting an SQL error (saying my apikey is null).

I tried overriding the `save` definition, but that seemed to cause problems when I updated the model, because it would override the values. I tried overriding the `initialize` definition, but that is returning a `nil:NilClass` and breaking things.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use callbacks and ||= ( = unless object is not nil ) :)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :add_apikey #or before_save

  private
  def add_apikey
    self.apikey ||= Digest::MD5.hexdigest(BCrypt::Password.create(self.password).to_s)
  end
end
```

but you should definitely take a look at [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise), [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) or [clearance](http://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) gems

Comment: I think `before_create` could be good but if he's validating presence of apikey, he'll need to do it in `before_validation`.

Comment: If I do `User.new(params)` then `@user.save` is the `before_create` filter run?

Comment: Yes, because the save is really acting as a create in this instance since `@user.new_record?` will return true.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with this solution, it seems to be fairly elegant and worked great! Thanks!

Comment: @webdestroya: What if two users have the same password?

Comment: @Ryan Bigg - Im not sure what you mean.. I am not using a password, it is just an APIKey used to authenticate. The APIkeys are checked to be unique

Comment: @webdestroya: The example shows `self.password`. I assume BCrypt doesn't do anything special for the same value, so if two users have the same password it's going to generate the same apikey for them.

Comment: @Ryan Bigg - No, everytime you run Bcrypt it will give you a new hash the salt just adds extra randomness

Answer (score 1):

What if, in your `save` definition, you check if the `apikey` is `nil`, and if so, you set it?

Comment: Is the `save` def called when `create!` is run? (Sorry, ruby noob)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) & in particular `before_validation`.

Comment: What I am trying to do is be able to pass an email to a new user object, and then create it. I want the model itself to generate an APIkey and a Secret, so that anytime I create a user, I know that the API key will be there.

Comment: I understand that. My point in the comment to Tadas' response is that if you are not accepting Users that have no apikey, you need to do it before_validation, and not before_create because before_create happens after validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User
    def self.create_user_with_digest(:options = { })
        self.create(:options)
        self.apikey = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(BCrypt::Password.create("jibberish").to_s)
        self.save
        return self
    end
end
```

Then you can call **User.create_user_with_digest(:name => "bob")** and you'll get a digest created automatically and assigned to the user, You probably want to generate the api key with another library than MD5 such as SHA256 you should also probably put some user enterable field, a continuously increasing number (such as the current date-time) and a salt as well.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works... just put the method in your `model`.

```
def apikey=(value)  
  self[:apikey] = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(BCrypt::Password.create("jibberish").to_s)  
end
```

Comment: I still need to be able to populate the user from the database, which stores the APIkey... will this solution present a problem, when I essentially try to assign a value to a function?